# Is there such a thing as inline conditional comments?

Tags: css, comments

I am required to support IE7 and above. There are a few page styling problems popping up in IE7 only, so I made a conditional IE7 style sheet which fixed most of the issues.

However, one piece of style was embedded inline by the coder so my IE7 style sheet won't be able to override the inline style (line one below).

```
<p style="display:inline-block; width:auto; margin:36px 0 0 16px !important;">
Download this postcard to help promote the Virtual Birth to Three (vBTT) Institute 
<span class="file_size">[PDF, 1MB]</span>.</p>
```

Can I put add an IE7 conditional statement inline to change the margin style?  I tried it and the commenting did not work inside the p element. Writing it this way:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
```

I suspect I can't do it at all, but I thought maybe someone here might know a trick.

If there's no trick, does everyone agree that I can't do it inline and must get the CSS out of the element and into the external style sheet to make changes?

Thanks very much for the input.  I hope this was the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot overwrite inline styles with any amount of CSS, you should be able to do it with javascript, you could use the conditional to load some javascript that will make those changes for you, although that's a bit clunky.

Even then it might not work as you're using the `!important` rule, I'm not sure how set-in-stone that style will be in IE7.

Your safest bet is to add a relevant class name or 2 to the tag and use the conditional to load another stylesheet that makes the changes you need for IE7.

Here is how you would include an IE7 specific stylesheet:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="ie7.css" type="text/css">
<[endif]-->
```

Comment: Would that be an additional, separate stylesheet from the general IE7 one I already made?  If I understand you correctly, it would be called at the instance of the inline code?

Comment: If you want to use pure CSS you'll have to get rid of those inline styles as they can't be overwritten.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: You _can_ normally override inline styles by specifying `!important` rules in your external stylesheet. However, in your example, `!important` has been specified in the inline rule(!), which is going to make this difficult/impossible. JavaScript _will_ be able to remove these inline styles.

Comment: Dunhamzzz, I already made the IE7 stylesheet to address other issues, as I mentioned in the question. The problem is that the inline !important overrides the ie7 styelsheet (as w3d pointed out above).